# MD5 of Data in Swift 3

Tags: swift, md5, swift3

I am trying to get MD5 hash of my data (image downloaded from the interweb). Unfortunately I have upgraded the framework to swift 3 and the method I have been using doesn't work now.

I have converted most of it but I am unable to get bytes out of the data:

```
import Foundation
import CommonCrypto


struct MD5 {

    static func get(data: Data) -> String {
        var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        CC_MD5(data.bytes, CC_LONG(data.count), &digest)

        var digestHex = ""
        for index in 0..<Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH) {
            digestHex += String(format: "%02x", digest[index])
        }

        return digestHex
    }

}
```

the CommonCrypto is already imported as a custom module. Problem is I am getting `'bytes' is unavailable: use withUnsafeBytes instead` on `CC_MD5(data.bytes,...`

So the question really is, how do I get the bytes out of the data and will this solution work?

Comment: Here's [my pure Swift implementation](https://github.com/NikolaiRuhe/SwiftDigest) that does not need CommonCrypto.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
    CC_MD5(data.bytes, CC_LONG(data.count), &digest)
```

As noted, `bytes` is unavailable because it's dangerous. It's a raw pointer into memory than can vanish. The recommended solution is to use `withUnsafeBytes` which promises that the target cannot vanish during the scope of the pointer. From memory, it would look something like this:

```
data.withUnsafeBytes { bytes in
    CC_MD5(bytes, CC_LONG(data.count), &digest)
}
```

The point is that the `bytes` pointer can't escape into scopes where `data` is no longer valid.

For an example of this with `CCHmac`, which is pretty similar to `MD5`, see [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor/blob/master/RNCryptor.swift#L650-L673).

Comment: I was looking for this answer way too long ! Thank you

Comment: Another reason why Swift is among the worse languages I've ever used: why not simply md5(blah:AnyObject) -> String :(

Comment: Your suggested syntax is extremely ambiguous and would lead to significant confusion (the same confusion I often encounter with developers who try to perform hashes in PHP and JavaScript and get unexpected and incorrect results that I have to walk them through fixing). But yes, if this were not magically bridged from C, and had a proper Swift interface, you're correct it should never look like this (because this magically bridged syntax is very ugly). It would be a simple method on Data and would return a Data. Probably Data.md5Hashed() or similar.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a one liner:

```
import CryptoKit
let md5String = Insecure.MD5.hash(data: data).map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
```

---

And for anyone that's interested, here's an example that you could build upon to support different Algorithms:

Usage:

```
Checksum.hash(data: data, using: .md5) == "MyMD5Hash"
```

Code Snippet:

```
import Foundation
import CommonCrypto

struct Checksum {
    private init() {}

    static func hash(data: Data, using algorithm: HashAlgorithm) -> String {
        /// Creates an array of unsigned 8 bit integers that contains zeros equal in amount to the digest length
        var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: algorithm.digestLength())

        /// Call corresponding digest calculation
        data.withUnsafeBytes {
            algorithm.digestCalculation(data: $0.baseAddress, len: UInt32(data.count), digestArray: &digest)
        }

        var hashString = ""
        /// Unpack each byte in the digest array and add them to the hashString
        for byte in digest {
            hashString += String(format:"%02x", UInt8(byte))
        }

        return hashString
    }

    /**
    * Hash using CommonCrypto
    * API exposed from CommonCrypto-60118.50.1:
    * https://opensource.apple.com/source/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto-60118.50.1/include/CommonDigest.h.auto.html
    **/
    enum HashAlgorithm {
        case md5
        case sha256

        func digestLength() -> Int {
            switch self {
            case .md5:
                return Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH)
            case .sha256:
                return Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH)
            }
        }

        /// CC_[HashAlgorithm] performs a digest calculation and places the result in the caller-supplied buffer for digest
        /// Calls the given closure with a pointer to the underlying unsafe bytes of the data's contiguous storage.
        func digestCalculation(data: UnsafeRawPointer!, len: UInt32, digestArray: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>!) {
            switch self {
            case .md5:
                CC_MD5(data, len, digestArray)
            case .sha256:
                CC_SHA256(data, len, digestArray)
            }
        }
    }
}
```